# About a noun before a comparative

Tags: comparative-constructions

I'm 20 years old, and he is 22 years old. 'I'm 2 years younger than him' is a right sentence. What about 'I'm 20 years younger than him' meaning I'm 20 years old, but I am younger than him.

Comment: If someone is 22 and you are "20 years younger than him" you are 2 years old.  That's a natural and grammatical phrase, but does not mean what you want it to mean.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't say "a **right** sentence" - use *correct* or *valid* or something instead. I can't think of many situations where we'd say "**a** right [something]", "a right answer" is the only one that comes to mind. "**The** right [something]" is fine, but that has a different meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't say that. But a comma could make a difference:

> I'm 20 years old, younger than him.

Answer (score 0):

You can just say I'm 20 and 2 years younger than him.

Comment: Any possibilities?